# Wine size window is too small

Tags: linux-mint, wine, window

I've installed Wine on Linux Mint 16 to run setup.exe files from Windows, but when I run the .exe file, a very small-sized window appears, the setup seems to work but I can't read anything.

The same happens when I run wine configurations, and so I think the problem is on Wine application.

This is what I get in my desktop:

[image]

The window looks minimized, but it's not possible to maximize or resize it.

Comment: Which wine version and what `setup.exe` files?

Comment: first i had 1.4 and then i used 1.6 and 1.7, but the same happened.   it doesn't matter what exe files i used because the wine configuration doesn't work aswell

Comment: Try deleting the `.wine` directory. `rm -rf ~/.wine`

Comment: i deleted the .wine but didn't solve it

Comment: Hod did you install wine?

Comment: well, at first i didn't have internet on my desktop so i had to install it "manually", transfering  the needed files from a machine with internet through a pen drive but i installed via command lines, but sometimes the terminal asked me to install some packages like flex, bison...i don't know if the installation was completely succeeded and then i'd like to reinstall everything again but i don't know how

Answer (score -1):

From what you have posted I recommend typing:

```
sudo apt-get purge wine
```

and press tab to get the autocomplete for the version (I would definitely purge and not remove in this case). Then do:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Then reinstall whatever is the stable version of wine in your distribution. Hopefully when you try again you will at least be able to see the configuration window.

Comment: Still not working.. Now i'm going to install it via Software Manager, see this link http://prntscr.com/2x1efv for what i should install.

Comment: I know winetricks worked when i installed it

Comment: I really don't recommend using the software manager. With the command line you can review the output to see if there are any configuration errors.

Comment: is there an alternative to Wine?

Comment: @user25371 there is Crossover, but this is paid software plus it is the same codebase as wine. The main thing you are paying for is tech support. They used to put features in that first before wine, but I think they stopped that so under the hood they are actually identical. Btw if purging and reinstalling doesn't help your issue and you have tried different versions in wine, the issue is most likely a bug in one of the libraries wine depends on. This will be hard to track down.

Comment: i remembered what i did initially, i installed wine from source code but when the terminal asked me about those missing necessary packages, it also asked about freetype development fonts but i could configure wine without it, now i am installing it again and now it will be a more complete installation

Comment: Yeah, it's solved! I used this tutorial: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Wine-on-Ubuntu

Comment: I think the problem was about the fonts that were missing there, i knew it could be something related to this, that's why i couldn't see one word in the window. Thanks Graeme for your help!